# Is this way to prove that union of powersets is not equal to powerset of union correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to disprove this statement:

**P(C) ∪ P (D) = P(C ∪ D)**

Union of powersets is equal to powerset of union

and here is my proof:

```
Let C = {2}, D = {3}

P(C) = {{}, {2}}

P(D) = {{}, {3}}

P(C) ∪ P (D) = {{}, {2}, {3}}

P(C ∪ D) =  {{}, {2}, {3}, {2, 3}}


P(C) ∪ P (D) ≠ P(C ∪ D)
```

Is there another way to proof this? Thank you

Comment: That's fine. The statement is false and you proved that by providing a counter-example.

Comment: That is correct. You have a counter-example which is enough to disprove the statement.

Comment: **Tip**: We can use some simpler sets. Use $\textrm{A}=\{1\}$ and $\textrm{B}=\{2\}$.

Answer (score 1):

if $P(C) \cup P(D)=P(C \cup D)$ then $P(C) \cup P(D) \subseteq P(C \cup D)$ and $P(C \cup D) \subseteq P(C) \cup P(D)$

So , you must also know that if $(X \subseteq Z )\land (Y \subseteq Z) $ then $(X \cup Y) \subseteq Z$

So , using thtis property , we can show that $P(C) \cup P(D) \subseteq P(C \cup D)$

but $P(C \cup D) \subseteq P(C) \cup P(D)$   is $NOT $ always true because we know that each set is subset of itself ,i.e,   $P(C \cup D)$ includes the subset constituted by the combination of whole elements but  $P(C) \cup P(D)$ cannot contain the subset which is constituted by all elements.